# Javascript validation using Number object

Tags: javascript

concider the following code:

```
var postValue = "99";
var number = new Number(postValue); //also tried var number = parseInt(postValue);
if (isNaN(number)) { 
              alert('please enter a number');
                        }
```

How come isNan(number) in both cases is false?

Comment: Works fine for me in both cases (FF24).

Comment: It's working as it should. **isNaN(x)** returns **true** if **x** is not a number else if **x** is a number it returns **false**. In your code **postValue** is a number as it has been implicitly converted to int from string.And **number** gets the value from **postValue** which is in your case **99**. So as **99** is a number it returns false and the alert doesn't show up.

Comment: The problem was elsewhere. I always use simplified versions of my problem. I used a hashtable to store errors. So if postValue is a string, the table gets filled with error info, but then after that when I validate with an integer, the validation is ok, but the value is still present in the table. stupid

Comment: So, when you validate with an integer you don't want to update the hashtable. Is that what you are talking about? It would be better if you could show something you worked on.

Comment: Yes I do wan't to update in that case. Problem was: wrong input -> put error in hashtable. But when I corrected the input, I forgot the error was still in the hastable..

Answer (score 2):

`isNAN` = "is **NOT** a number". This means that, if `isNaN(number) === false`, then `number` **IS** a number:

```
var postValue = "99";
var number = parseInt(postValue);
if (isNaN(number)) { 
    alert('please enter a number');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`parseInt()` will convert your string to an integer. To do so, it reads characters from the left of the string to find as many number characters as it can, then returns that number.

In this case, since `"99"` is all numeric characters, the result is the number 99. Which is very clearly "not-not a number" and therefore `isNaN` returns false.

`isNaN` will return true if the input string starts with something that isn't a digit.

Answer (score 0):

`isNaN()` : Is Not a Number, would return false when the argument is not a NUMBER. 
Which is the case for you code. You always get a number in both the cases.